# How to get any user public images on instagram via api?

Tags: instagram-api

Is there any way I can get any user public images on instagram via api
I am using 
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT-ID`
endpoint to fetch my own instagram account images but not able to fetch other users images.

Comment: How did you try to get other users' posts? Please include that to your question. Also, why did it not work? Did you get an error message or did nothing happen at all? Please also include that to your question.

Comment: it was easy, sorry to bother you guys
https://www.instagram.com/user?__a=1